# Efficient way to parse HTML dump found in the form of string

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup, htmleditorkit

Please deal with this trivial question. It is available in bits and pieces on stackoverflow.

I have HTML dump of a website in the form of String. I want to extract text from the specific tags of it.

In other way, I want to mimic

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("cite");
```

I am not using Jsoup because I don't want it to connect to the website (I have another service for that which returns html dump in the form of text). I found [HTMLEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) for converting text to HTMLDocument but it doesn't seem to be very easy to use(like Jsoup or HTMLParser) or I am unable to get it.

Any help would be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used Jsoup and it worked yet, you should continue using it.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html>...");
```

should do.

see: [The API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Or more fully, `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myHtmlString);`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :) I was so dumb to not try this!